# How To Get My Rails Phusion Apache App To Use The Correct DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

enter code hereOk this is obviously a rookie mistake of some description but I have followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6) to the letter and cannot get my rails app public directory to be my document root.

the tutorial says put this code in httpd.conf:

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /home/pollylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so

   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /home/pollylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.45
     PassengerDefaultRuby /home/pollylan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby
   </IfModule>


   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.yourhost.com
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /somewhere/public    
      <Directory /somewhere/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
         # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
         #Require all granted
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

- As far as I can tell the first part is fine. In the second block *:80 throws this error: `VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results`.

So I changed the * to my IP address.. And obviously to the public directory of my app which is /home/[username]/site/public

but the server still points to /home/[username]/public_html. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.. I don't think that I'm editing the wrong httpd.conf file (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf). Also I don't know if I need a virtual host because I have only one domain name at present if that makes any difference.. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

:)

I'm using:

CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 4.1.1
RVM
Phusion Passenger version 4.0.45

Comment: Did you boot a new vm, or are you using an existing one you have?

Comment: I'm using a new VPS but I didn't boot it myself it's the default install.